# Calculating number of occurrences and entering and appending them to csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

What I need to do is calculate the following:

1. The number of times a person appears in the list on dates prior to the date specified in the row and a 1 occurs in column 7.
2. The number of times a person (column 8) appears in the list on dates prior to the date specified in the row (note they are sorted chronologically.)

It might be easier to demonstrate this with an example, raw data from csv.

```
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith
02/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips
```

What I need the csv to look like as a result of following the described instructions:

```
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,1,2
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly,0,1
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith,1,2
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James,0,1
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,1,2
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith,1,4
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith,1,4
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith,1,4
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips,0,3
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly,1,2
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James,0,2
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith,2,7
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly,1,2
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips,0,5
```

So you can see that on the last row Tom Phillips had occurred 5 times on days previous to this one (column 10) and of those 5 occurrences there had been zero occurrences of column 7 being "1".

My csv data is obviously much larger than this, so efficient techniques and suggestions would also be appreciated. If more clarification is required please say so, its hard to tell if this example is understandable.

Comment: How many rows do you need to parse?

Comment: 156,000 and once I have managed to get a piece of code that can do this, I will be reverse engineering it and re using it for about another hundred times in the same set of data.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple one:

```
import csv
import datetime
import copy
from collections import defaultdict

with open(r"C:\Temp\test.csv") as i, open(r"C:\Temp\resuls.csv", "wb") as o:
    rdr = csv.reader(i)
    wrt = csv.writer(o)

    data, currdate = defaultdict(lambda:[0, 0, 0, 0]), None
    for line in rdr:
        date, name = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%d/%m/%Y'), line[7]

        if date != currdate or not currdate:
            for v in data.itervalues(): v[:2] = v[2:]
            currdate = date

        wrt.writerow(line + data[name][:2])

        data[name][3] += 1
        if line[6] == "1": data[name][2] += 1
```

One with deepcopy:

```
import csv
import datetime
import copy
from collections import defaultdict

with open(r"C:\Temp\test.csv") as i, open(r"C:\Temp\resuls.csv", "wb") as o:
    rdr, wrt = csv.reader(i), csv.writer(o)

    curr, currdate = defaultdict(lambda:[0, 0]), None
    for line in rdr:
        date, name = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%d/%m/%Y'), line[7]

        if date != currdate or not currdate:
            prev = copy.deepcopy(curr)
            currdate = date

        wrt.writerow(line + prev[name])

        curr[name][1] += 1
        if line[6] == "1": curr[name][0] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative answer, now to find out which one is more efficient. :)

Comment: @AEA changed solution a bit ({} -> defaultdict)

Comment: @AEA also missed that file should be opened in "wb" mode, changed

Comment: No worries still formatting the csv for testing :) Many thanks. I will report the results of this to both of you :)

Comment: @AEA missed your note about efficiency, may be I'll have to check deepcopy efficiency and change solution

Comment: added solution without deepcopy, I think i should be faster

Comment: This is very interesting to me, I am relatively new to coding, and to python but am obsessed with efficiency and have some large datasets to analyse :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38300/discussion-between-aea-and-roman-pekar)

Comment: I made a mistake in my question in that the time format should be as follows: 01/01/2002 rather than Jan-1, I attempted to make the code work in accordance with this, but to no avail. I will edit my example data & output data. Kind regards AEA

Comment: Hi Roman, there was a small edit to the dataset too (apologies) I have removed the commas on the end (which were there by mistake.) Your code is now deleting the names in the csv.

Comment: I attempted to edit your code to look for a match with more than one parameter, but to no avail. I have listed a dual parameter version of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123871/calculating-number-of-occurrences-of-dual-parameter-match-in-a-csv-appending-the

Comment: I'm out of computer now, but looks like you csn use tuple (person, data) as key of dictionary. I'll try to look at your question a bit later

Comment: Cheers Roman, you wouldn't believe how many times I have used and manipulated the answer above already!

Comment: @AEA had absolutely no time, do you still need the answer for second question?

Comment: yes please! You dont realise how much I will be using and manipulating your code!

Comment: Hi @RomanPekar I have been trying to use this code in a variety of different ways, however I still dont fully understand it. Would it be possible for you to add some comments to the script to describe how it works. *Note* I am using the Simple one, since this proved the fastest in tests. Thanks in advance AEA

Comment: In the time I have been coding (about 4 months) I have acquired a few coding methods, which normally enable me to get by. However in this code there seems to be a few methods i do not understand. Such as lambda and the itervalues part too. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AEA, itervalues is just dict method to get all the values inside dict, lambda is anonymous function