# Calculating number of occurrences of dual parameter match in a csv appending the results to csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, append, match

What I need to do is calculate the following:

The number of times a person appears in the list (column 8) on dates prior to the date specified in the row with the same t data in column 10 and a 1 occurs in column 7.

The number of times a person (column 8) appears in the list on dates prior to the date specified in the row and with the same t data in column 10 (note they are sorted chronologically.)

It might be easier to demonstrate this with an example, raw data from csv.

```
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith,data,15t
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James,data,22t
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly,data,22t
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith,data,25t
02/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips,data,15t
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips,data,25t
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,data,22t
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,data,25t
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly,data,25t
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith,data,15t
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James,data,25t
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,data,22t
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith,data,22t
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith,data,25t
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith,data,15t
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips,data,25t
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly,data,25t
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James,data,22t
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith,data,22t
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly,data,25t
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips,data,15t
```

What I need the csv to look like as a result of following the described instructions:

```
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith,data,15t,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James,data,22t,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly,data,22t,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith,data,25t,0,0
02/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips,data,15t,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips,data,25t,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,data,22t,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,data,25t,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly,data,25t,0,0
03/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith,data,15t,1,1
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James,data,25t,0,0
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,data,22t,0,0
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith,data,22t,0,1
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith,data,25t,0,1
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith,data,15t,1,2
04/01/2005,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips,data,25t,0,2
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly,data,25t,1,1
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James,data,22t,0,1
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith,data,22t,0,2
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly,data,25t,1,1
05/01/2005,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips,data,15t,0,1
```

So you can see that on the last row Tom Phillips with 15t had occurred 1 times on days previous to this one (column 10) and of those 1 occurrences there had been zero occurrences of column 7 being "1".

My csv data is obviously much larger than this, so efficient techniques and suggestions would also be appreciated. If more clarification is required please say so, its hard to tell if this example is understandable.

Kind regards AEA

Comment: did you try using the [csv](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: I tired making a direct edit on this single parameter version piece of code however to no avail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040917/calculating-number-of-occurrences-and-entering-and-appending-them-to-csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

very minor change:

```
import csv
import datetime
import copy
from collections import defaultdict

with open(r"C:\Temp\test2.csv") as i, open(r"C:\Temp\results2.csv", "wb") as o:
    rdr = csv.reader(i)
    wrt = csv.writer(o)

    # data is a dictionary where we will save current and previous data like:
    # {
    #    (George Smith, 15t): [
    #         previous date count when column 7 = 1,
    #         previous date count,
    #         current date count when column 7 = 1,
    #         current date count
    #    ]
    data, currdate = defaultdict(lambda:[0, 0, 0, 0]), None
    for line in rdr:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%d/%m/%Y')

        # key of dictionary would be tuple looking like
        # (George Smith, 15t)
        name = (line[7], line[9])

        # if date is changed, we have to put current values into previous
        # by copying part of the list
        #
        #    (George Smith, 15t): [
        #         previous date count when column 7 = 1,
        #         previous date count,
        #         current date count when column 7 = 1,
        #         current date count
        #    ]
        #
        # becomes
        #
        #    (George Smith, 15t): [
        #         current date count when column 7 = 1,
        #         current date count
        #         current date count when column 7 = 1,
        #         current date count
        #    ]
        # and then we change currdate variable to current one

        if date != currdate or not currdate:
            for v in data.itervalues(): v[:2] = v[2:]
            currdate = date

        # writing current line + first 2 elements from list (previous counts)
        wrt.writerow(line + data[name][:2])

        # updating current counts
        data[name][3] += 1
        if line[6] == "1": data[name][2] += 1
```

Comment: Hoped it might be, now I hope to reverse engineer your changes to work out how to do a 3 way match :) (I really hope I don't have to post that one! )

Comment: you can use tuples of any length as key fo dictionary, so I think it will be easy for you

Comment: Many thanks again, it my analysis protocol I can literally imagine myself using these two pieces of code 200+ times

Comment: Hey Roman, there isn't any chance of getting you to comment the hell out of the above answer is there? I know its cheeky, but It will help immensely.

Comment: Hi, no problem! Do you want me to explain exact part?